# в чем различие между getElementById i getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

Собственно сам вопрос: почему когда пишу код по `getElementById` работает, а с `getElementsByclassName` не работает ??

Это рабочий код

```
var img = document.getElementById('images');
var imagesArray = ["img/flower1.jpg", "img/flower2.jpg", "img/flower3.jpg", 
 "img/flower5.jpg", "img/flower6.jpg"];
var index = 0;

function changeimg(){
    img.setAttribute("src" ,imagesArray[index]);
    imdex++;
    if (imdex >= imagesArray.length) {
        imdex = 0;
    }
}

setInterval(changeimg, 5000);
```

Это не рабочий код

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('images');
var imagesArray = ["img/flower1.jpg", "img/flower2.jpg", "img/flower3.jpg", 
 "img/flower5.jpg", "img/flower6.jpg"];
var index = 0;

function changeimg(){
    img.setAttribute("src" ,imagesArray[index]);
    imdex++;
    if (imdex >= imagesArray.length) {
        imdex = 0;
    }
}

setInterval(changeimg, 5000);
```

Comment: Попробуйте `img[imdex].src = ...`

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsById` - это один элемент, а `getElementsByClassName` - это живая коллекция элементов. Вообще где указано `getElements` - это живая коллекция с элементами.

И что бы обратиться к элементу по `getElementsByClassName` нужно указывать индекс элемента, к которому ты хочешь обратиться. А если ты хочешь ко всем элементом с данным классом, то нужно создавать цикл:

***Пример:***

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('class');

for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){
  elem[i].innerHTML = 'Код'
};
```

---

Так же можно обращаться через новые функции: `querySelector` и `querySelectorAll`

`document.querySelector('query selector')` - это первый элемент с данным селектором.
`document.querySelectorAll('query selector')` - все элементы с данным селектором (коллекция элементов. Нужно обращаться через индекс).

Чем примечательная эта функция, так это тем, что в ней можно указывать те же селекторы, что и в *CSS*. То есть, можно обратиться к элементам по атрибуту - `[атрибут="его значение"]`, по классу `.element`, по ID - `#elem` и по всем другим *query* селекторам.

Comment: Это не массив. Это другая коллекция, причём живая.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не все поймут, что такое живая коллекция

Comment: Это не повод заведомо неверно её называть. Например, я в своём ответе сказал просто "коллекция" без дополнительных уточнений. Но если хочется расписать, то можно и поподробнеее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ой всё :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, редактировал

Comment: Уже заметил и плюс поставил)

Answer (score 1):

```
getElementById
getElementsByClassName
          ^
```

Второй возвращает коллекцию элементов, а не 1 элемент, как первый.

Answer (score 1):

Потому не работает, что `getElementById` возвращает один элемент, а `getElementsByClassName` возвращает массив элементов.

Чтобы получить первый элемент попробуйте написать так:

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('images')[0];
```

Литература:

[MDN: document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)

[MDN: document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)