# getElementsByClassName не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, методы, counter

Здравствуйте!

Есть такой див-элемент (счетчик товара):

```
    <div class="input-group quantity_goods">
      <input type="button" value="-" id="button_minus" class="minus">
      <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="10" id="num_count" class="count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty">
      <input type="button" value="+" id="button_plus" class="plus">
    </div>
```

И к нему скрипт:

```
    var numCount = document.getElementsByClassName('count');
    var plusBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('plus');
    var minusBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('minus');
    plusBtn.onclick = function() {
      var qty = parseInt(numCount.value);
      qty = qty + 1;
      numCount.value = qty;}
    minusBtn.onclick = function() {
      var qty = parseInt(numCount.value);
      qty = qty - 1;
      if (qty < 1)
        qty = qty + 1;
      numCount.value = qty;}
```

Удивительным (для меня) образом этот код не срабатывает, но если поменять getElementsByClassName на getElementById с соответсвующими айдишниками, то код становится рабочим для первого счетчика. Но счетчиков предполагается несколько на странице.

Подозреваю, что я не понимаю какого-то базового принципа работы getElementsByClassName, поэтому в коде чего-то нехватает.

Пожалуйста, тыкните меня носом в ошибку, буду премного благодарна.

Comment: классика жанра. + еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637915/191482 и в целом поиск https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=getElementsByClassName  ......... но суть должна быть понятна из ссылки на дубликат

Comment: @АлексейШиманский? спасибо, теперь всё понятно) Я вообще неправильно понимала для себя что возвращает getElementsByClassName. На самом деле мне нужен был querySelector.

Comment: Ну если судить по диву с классом `input-group`, то у тебя таких групп может быть несколько, а значит тебе придется использовать либо querySelector**All** либо getElementsByClassName так или иначе